# Content script on chrome error page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I run my extension content script on Google Chrome error page?

For example on the "This webpage is not available" error page? Here is my manifest.json config:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "injectbox",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "bg.js" ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [  
    {
      "js": [ "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    {
      "js": [ "content.js" ],
      "css":["styles.css"],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*", "ftp://*/*",
    "webRequest",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can access Chrome error page from an extension (same for local pages).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, most probably this is an internal `chrome://` page, which are excluded from page matches.

An alternative solution would be to listen to error events in `webRequest`/`webNavigation` APIs and replace the error page with your own.