# How to make Chrome extension workable even page says ERR_CONNECTION_RES

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a google chrome extension which replaces url to another if page is not available.I mean it responses 
*The server DNS address of the example.com host machine could not be found.
*ERR_CONNECTON_RES

or same as these stuations.

I have searched how extensions work and found these extentions run after DOM is completed.But i believe that there is no impossible thing.

Is there a any code i can add to run the extension before DOM is completed to content.js.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to work with just content scripts; those [cannot be used on Chrome error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502927/content-script-on-chrome-error-page).

So, you'll need a background page and some API event to listen to for the specific case of network errors.

`webNavigation` API seems to be a good fit, e.g. [`webNavigation.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred).